# How to find and replace all percent, plus, and pipe signs?

Tags: sed

I have a document containing many percent, plus, and pipe signs. I want to replace them with a code, for use in TeX.

- `%` becomes `\textpercent`.
- `+` becomes `\textplus`.
- `|` becomes `\textbar`.

This is the code I am using, but it does not work:

```sh
sed -i "s/\%/\\\textpercent /g" ./file.txt
sed -i "s/|/\\\textbar /g" ./file.txt
sed -i "s/\+/\\\textplus /g" ./file.txt
```

How can I replace these symbols with this code?

Comment: the command u mentioned works at my place.

Comment: You can combine all three in a single sed script, and lose the gratuitous backslashes. `sed -i -e 's/%/\\textpercent /g;s/+/\\textplus /g;s/|/\\textbar /g' file.txt`

Comment: To "successfully replace every percent, plus, and pipe sign from my files" you will have to provide us your files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Test script:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat << 'EOF' > testfile.txt
1+2+3=6
12 is 50% of 24
The pipe character '|' looks like a vertical line.
EOF

sed -i -r 's/%/\\textpercent /g;s/[+]/\\textplus /g;s/[|]/\\textbar /g' testfile.txt

cat testfile.txt
```

**Output:**

```
1\textplus 2\textplus 3=6
12 is 50\textpercent  of 24
The pipe character '\textbar ' looks like a vertical line.
```

This was already suggested in a similar way by @tripleee, and I see no reason why it should not work. As you can see, my platform uses the very same version of GNU sed as yours. The only difference to @tripleee's version is that I use the extended regex mode, so I have to either escape the pipe and the plus or put it into a character class with `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
nawk '{sub(/%/,"\\textpercent");sub(/\+/,"\\textplus");sub(/\|/,"\\textpipe"); print}' file
```

Tested below:

```
> echo "% + |" | nawk '{sub(/%/,"\\textpercent");sub(/\+/,"\\textplus");sub(/\|/,"\\textpipe"); print}'
\textpercent \textplus \textpipe
```

Comment: Is there a way to make these changes happen to the same file, without having to send the results to a new file?

Comment: Nice! nawk and gawk are pretty darn powerful! Highly recommended, after having skimmed through their man pages and a little of the online docs. (See also: gsub command in nawk/gawk, which replaces all occurrences, not just the first one.)

Comment: @Village You can redirect output to a file by simply putting `> filePath` at the end (where filePath is e.g. `/home/username/myfile`).

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes:

```
$ cat in.txt 
foo % bar
foo + bar
foo | bar
$ sed -e 's/%/\\textpercent /g' -e 's/\+/\\textplus /g' -e 's/|/\\textbar /g' < in.txt 
foo \textpercent  bar
foo \textplus  bar
foo \textbar  bar
```

Comment: ...and perhaps use another delimiter than `/`, for readability. May I suggest a `#`

Comment: I don't see the need to use another delimiter since `/` is *only* used as a delimiter here.